# Importjson to google spreadsheet, one field gives several results

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I am trying to make a tracking system for our post @ work, and so far I feel that I am 90% done, but I get one problem.

I have added this script to google spreadsheet:[https://gist.github.com/chrislkeller/5719258](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chrislkeller/5719258/raw/46da3483d6d444c4c1d0bcae666a366636561db5/import_json_appsscript.js)

Now, I am trying to pull out data with this "command":

```
=ImportJSON("https://tracking.bring.com/api/tracking.json?q="&A4;"/consignmentSet/packageSet/eventSet/recipientSignature,/consignmentSet/packageSet/eventSet/status,/consignmentSet/senderReference,/consignmentSet/packageSet/productName";"noInherit,noHeaders")
```

And this works, but it gives me multiple results on status:

```
/consignmentSet/packageSet/eventSet/status
```

If you see source, it have several "STATUS" in the source https://tracking.bring.com/api/tracking.json?q=TESTPACKAGE-AT-PICKUPPOINT, and this is the reason why it get all the results. What I want, is to get the last result for status in my google spreadsheet. This to give it a more clean look, and also to have less used cells for no use. The url provided, is a test package for bring, but when we send out, it will get even more "STATUS" up to 5 different status.

TLDR: Want to get one result for status, not several as shown in--> https://tracking.bring.com/api/tracking.json?q=TESTPACKAGE-AT-PICKUPPOINT when importing data to google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the final output array. For that add/modify the following lines to the `parseJSONObject_` function

```
var temp =  data.slice(1);
var final_data = [[temp[0][0],temp[temp.length-1][1],temp[temp.length-1][2],temp[0][3]]];
return hasOption_(options, "noHeaders") ? (data.length > 1 ? final_data : new Array()) : data;
```

**Entire Function:**

```
/** 
 * Parses a JSON object and returns a two-dimensional array containing the data of that object.
 */
function parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var headers = new Array();
  var data    = new Array();

  if (query && !Array.isArray(query) && query.toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
    query = query.toString().split(",");
  }

  if (options) {
    options = options.toString().split(",");
  }

  parseData_(headers, data, "", 1, object, query, options, includeFunc);
  parseHeaders_(headers, data);
  transformData_(data, options, transformFunc);

  var temp =  data.slice(1);
  var final_data = [[temp[0][0],temp[0][1],temp[0][2],temp[0][3]]]; // Modified the index of the array
  return hasOption_(options, "noHeaders") ? (data.length > 1 ? final_data : new Array()) : data;
}
```

Comment: @user8933804, I have modified the code to get the latest status